# How to run multiple successive select buttons in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I facing an issue with having multiple selects in angularJS where each one of them is linked to the previous one and the value depended on the previous item selected which looks like could be done easily by angular but I am having a hard time figuring out how do I make the index of one select be passed to another select and at the same time making it unresponsive until some value is selected.

I also created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saras_arya/1nzk5nsw/1/) for the same for people to fiddle around with it.

Here is the concerned HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <select ng-model="carBrand" name="carBrand" required ng-options=" brand for brand in brands"></select>
    <select ng-model="carModel" name="carModel" required ng-options="model.name for model in cars[0]"></select>
    <!--I want the car brand(cars[0]) to be dynamic here. It should be prefreberably blacked out or uneditable until a Car brand is selected and once that particular brand is selected all the models pertaining to that brand only should be displayed in the ajoining select button-->
  </div>
</div>
```

and an example app.js. Find the  complete one at the fiddle

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("testController", function($scope) {
  $scope.brands = ['Ford', 'Honda', 'Hyundai', 'Mahindra',
    'Maruti Suzuki', 'Nissan', 'Renault', 'Skoda', 'Tata', 'Toyota', 'Volksvagen'
  ];
  $scope.carBrand = $scope.brands[0];
  $scope.cars = [];
  /*These cars[0] and cars[1] are static declared but could well be called from a REST API endpoint in angular. For simplicity lets say they are already present. */
  $scope.cars[0] = $scope.cars[0] = [{
    name: "Figo",
    capacity: 45
  }, {
    name: "Ecosport",
    capacity: 52
  }, {
    name: "Fiesta",
    capacity: 45
  }, {
    name: "Endeavour",
    capacity: 71
  }];
});
```

How do I solve the issue of getting an index from one select and passing it to the other to make this work and probably an additional perk would be to make it unresponsive in case no brand is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ng-change`:

```
<select ng-model="carBrand" name="carBrand" required ng-options=" brand for brand in brands" 
ng-change="selectedCar(carBrand)"></select>
```

This returns the index of the selected brand:

```
$scope.selectedCar = function(brand) {
  $scope.carIndex = $scope.brands.indexOf(brand);
};
```

Use it with the other dropdown as:

```
<select ng-model="carModel" name="carModel" required 
ng-options="model.name for model in cars[carIndex]"></select>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwhw2ovx/)

Answer (score 1):

When you select something from the first select, `carBrand` goes from `undefined` to the selected brand. You thus want the second select to be disabled if the `carBrand` is undefined (falsy):

```
<select ng-disabled="!carBrand" ...>
```

Then, you need to second select to contain the models associated to the selected brand (which is `carBrand`). So you need something like

```
<select ng-options="model.name for model in getModelsOfBrand(carBrand)" ...>
```

Now just implement this `getModelsOfBrand(carBrand)` function in the scope. It would be much easier if you had a better object model, like for example:

```
$scope.brands = [
    {
        name: 'Ford',
        models: [
            {
                name: 'Figo',
                capacity: 45
            }, 
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
];
```

Then it would be as easy as

```
<select ng-options="model.name for model in carBrand.models" ...>
```