# How to programmatically fill values in successive select in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Programmatically

So I am facing an issue with the select in Angular JS. This is a follow-up question to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806216/how-to-run-multiple-successive-select-buttons-in-angularjs)
Now I am able to load my values in the second select but I am unable to write the same value to it when the query from DB comes back. So If I select Ford in one select and Figo in another. and press save. The values go into DB correctly but when I come again to that view. Shouldn't that value persist right? I mean I should be able to see figo in the second select. But I am unable to. I tried setting to the ng-model but that method doesn't work. I have also attached a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saras_arya/hwkbn7Lp/) with the proper comments as to what is not working.

The code uses one of the marked answers from the question.

HTML

```
<select ng-model="carBrand" name="carBrand" required ng-options=" brand for brand in brands" ng-change="selectedCar(carBrand)"></select>
    <select ng-model="carModel" name="carModel" required ng-options="model.name for model in cars[carIndex]"></select>
```

JS

```
$scope.brands = ['Ford', 'Honda', 'Hyundai', 'Mahindra',
    'Maruti Suzuki', 'Nissan', 'Renault', 'Skoda', 'Tata', 'Toyota', 'Volksvagen'
  ];
$scope.cars[0] = $scope.cars[0] = [{
    name: "Figo",
    capacity: 45
  }, {
    name: "Ecosport",
    capacity: 52
  }, {
    name: "Fiesta",
    capacity: 45
  }, {
    name: "Endeavour",
    capacity: 71
  }];
  $scope.carBrand = $scope.brands[0];
  $scope.cars = [];

  $scope.selectedCar = function(brand) {
    $scope.carIndex = $scope.brands.indexOf(brand);
  };
  $scope.carModel = "Anything";
```

**EDIT**
I think there is an issue in the understanding of the question. All I want is programmatically(by code) set the value of the second select. That's it.

Comment: there is no save in your fiddle

Comment: when u do submit what r u doing are u refreshing or redirecting to different page and come back ?

Comment: I am refreshing that calling the database again.

Comment: Whenever I come back on that page I have created a refresh function. It is called whenever I come in that view or I make a post

Comment: better create a fiddle did u make empty the dropdowns check my above comment

Comment: @gayathri could you post that as an answer and explain your approach more as it looks very abstract

Comment: I have already created a fiddle.  Please check the question

Comment: there is no more save ryt

Comment: Yeah save and all is a functionally that is implemented in my app.  What i am trying to do here is recreate the minimum version of my issue which is  in angular. Which is replicated in the fiddle.

Comment: how do you expect it to remember the page elements after refreshing the page ?

Comment: @alok I have created a refresh function. Which is called everytime a page is refreshed. it remembers all the values as the id is saved in a cookie on which I make a database call everytime

Comment: if u refresh it will be gone unless store in localstorage and assign again

Comment: that is a fair way of doing it. May I ask why are you refreshing everything

Comment: I want it to be consistent with the database @alok.  Whenever I do a post I make sure the refreshed values are coming from DB.  So that even if he comes back the values are coming from db.  This is just to ensure 100% same response everywhere.

Comment: Isn't the best way to make things consistent is have only one source ??

Comment: Yes that source is database

Answer (score 0):

I have forked your fiddle. Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/4ynkrj0o/2/

```
var MockSaveMyData = function(itemsToSave){
 // I JUST SAVED ALL MY DATE !! :D
 var savedItems = itemsToSave;
 savedItems.CreatedAt = new Date();
 savedItems.CreatedBy = 'YOU !!';

 return {
      then: function(callback){
       callback(savedItems);
   }
 };
};
```

You will have to save and retrieve the values on every page refresh.
Like you said, you have cookies where you save your Car object. In that case, you will have to assign the object on the top firth thing inside the controller.

You will also have to update the cookies after you have run the save function. I will suggest doing all this in the success call back which http calls provide. You can update the cookie and then refresh the page. Or you can just assign the updated values and give a message to the user stating that the save call has been successful.

Again, in my opinion, you should avoid reloading the page. It almost defies the essence of Angular. Where you can do almost everything asynchronously.

Comment: Alok I think you are missing the point. The point being, I just want some value in the second select button that is added by code and not my literally selecting it. Thats it. Thats the issue.

Comment: So you make a request based on what you select in the first dropdown and then populate the second dropdown with the returned data ??

Comment: The relationship is like brand and model. Both are there locally.  Both are saved in db.  While getting from db.  Brand I can set programmatically but not the model because it's not a simple select. It's based on values of brand

Comment: You do realize that you don't need to make make the second call once the user has selected one. You can treat them independently if there is an available second selection.